# -include causes make to ignore --just-print or -n directive

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

It seems that the presence of `-include` cause make to ignore `--just-print`/`-n` flags. This is undesirable.

I would like to understand why this is. My example `Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: all
all: eg.final.d

define MYRULE
$(1).targets:
    echo 'final1.txt\nfinal2.txt\nfinal3.txt' > $$@

$(1).final.d: $(1).targets
    cat $$< | sed 's/$$$$/: initial.txt/' > $$@

-include $(1).final.d
endef

$(eval $(call MYRULE, eg))
```

When `make -n all` is issued the targets are all created (as opposed to just printing the commands to be run as expected). using `$(info ..)` did not help me figure out what is going on here.

#### Update

My attempt at what seems to be preferable given reading [this blog post](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/):

```
.PHONY: all
all: eg.final.d

define MYRULE
$(1).targets:
    echo 'final1.txt\nfinal2.txt\nfinal3.txt' > $$@

$(1).final.d: $(1).targets
    cat $$< | sed 's/$$$$/: initial.txt/' > $$@
endef

$(eval $(call MYRULE, eg))
-include $(wildcard *.final.d)
```

taking the include statement out of the define variable and including the generated dependencies after the eval call prevents the recipe always being executed.

#### Update 2

when this recipe is run `input.egtool.log` is made and a >0 number of other files (`OTHER_FILES`)

```
input.egtool.log: input.txt
    egtool $< > $@
```

b/c of unfortunate reasons, I do not know what the exact names of these other files will be ahead of time (but for the same input always get same output). The names of these other files are however written to the log file. I wish to keep and use these other files downstream and so I want set them to depend on the above `input.egtool.log` recipe (or at least its output) and include these dependencies in my makefile:

```
OTHER_FILES = ???HELP???
$(OTHER_FILES): input.egtool.log

.PHONY: all
all: $(OTHER_FILES)
```

this way if input.txt changes `OTHER_FILES` also changes appropriately. I tried to do this via the above but my approaches are incorrect.

Comment: There's a problem with this.  `wildcard` only matches files _that already exist_ when the makefile is parsed.  If there are no `*.final.d` files that exist when make starts, then nothing will be included and no prerequisites will be defined.  As long as you always build `eg.final.d` as your target this will be OK, I think (it's kind of a confusing way to do things), but if you run `make eg.target` you may get incorrect results since `eg.final.d` will never be built.

Comment: @MadScientist thanks for the input. If you can take time please have a look at the update 2 section where I describe the problem more clearly instead of my incorrect attempts at a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior in your makefile.  See the description of `-n` in the *[Instead of Executing Recipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Instead-of-Execution.html)* section of the GNU make manual:

> “No-op”. Causes make to print the recipes that are needed to make the targets up to date, but not actually execute them. Note that some recipes are still executed, even with this flag (see How the MAKE Variable Works). Also any recipes needed to update included makefiles are still executed (see How Makefiles Are Remade).

Note n particular the last sentence here.

I recommend against using this model of auto-dependency generation.  For a better method, see for example [this blog post](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/) on auto-dependency generation.

Comment: I did read this I guess I am not understanding the order of execution that results in the included file being needed to update. Your post is informative, had tried to read through but got lost on how to implement my basic example above using the mentioned strategies. Will attempt some more (note that I don't have a gcc/precompiler tool that would suit for above)

Comment: Maybe you're getting confused by the eval stuff you're trying to do?  All of that is totally irrelevant for this issue: it will behave identically if you write the rules directly without `eval`/`call`/`define`.  When make sees your `eval` it will be expanded right there and make only internalizes the expansion result.  Once the entire makefile is parsed, then it will try to rebuild included `.d` files.  Each `.d` file depends on `.targets`, so make will try to rebuild that as well.  As the manual says, this ignores the `-n` setting.

Comment: You don't need GCC.  You  have a command that generates the `.d` file.  You just have to put that command into the same recipe that is used to build the target itself.  That's all the blog post is talking about.  GCC has a way to do it all at the same time which is more efficient but you can just make another command line in the same recipe.

Comment: have updated question with what passes as an explanation. accepting as most helpful in helping me find the answer to my question.